# translate content of svg image

Tags: wordpress, svg, text, google-translate

I have an svg image, with text, that should be translated automatically. I'm using wordpress GTranslate plugin, however the text in the svg is not translated even though it is embedded directly into the page, with  tags around it. How do I solve this problem?

For testing go to https://www.derigo.dk/om-os/

pressing the english flag, will translate all the other text in the page.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking this on the [GTranslate support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/gtranslate/) rather than here.

Comment: @RobertLongson thx very much for the link - I asked in there as well, I was just unaware whether there was a more overarching google translate best practice to get SVG's translated, but it seems from my googling, that it's a bit of a niche issue. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Please take a look at the [switch element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/switch-element.html). It may be what you need.